# Feature extraction using convolutional neural network?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

i have a problem in digit recognition. In feature extraction part, I have to use some convolutional masks (like the figure 4.23 in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313336/question-about-convolutional-neural-network)) to get the feature maps and the OUTPUT. However, i don't what kind of masks i need and how to get the mask? (In some papers, maybe they used Back-Propagation, but i don't know how to use it) Can you show me some masks used in this part, or how to get them?
Thank you very much! Any suggestion is welcom!

Comment: if you got an answer, please mark your question as closed.

Comment: sr, but actually, i'm still confusing!!

Answer (score 0):

Back-propagation is about training your Neural Network after setting the architecture. I never used neural networks for digit recognition problem but here is a link about Recognition of Handwritten Digits: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/NeuralNetRecognition.aspx#Training). and it has some code samples.

Good luck.

Comment: Just curious, what do you use for OCR if not NN?

Answer (score 0):

In a CNN you normally have a 2D image as an input data, let's say a Black&White 28x28x1 (horizontal, vertical, channels) digit as in MNIST.

Then you create a 2d Kernel (as an example a 3x3 kernel) that slides over the input image pixels with a defined **stride** (how much pixels it moves horizontally/vertically each step) and **padding** (how many pixels with value 0 to add to all sides to have the sliding kernel center to be able to cover each pixels of the image when arriving at its borders).

Let' say the used Kernel=3x3, Padding=1, Stride=1.

This kernel, applied in convolution while sliding, will also generate a 28x28 image where each pixel is the convolution of the kernel with a different area of the input image.

If instead of just one kernel, you create 16 of them, after the convolution you'll obtain 16 28x28 images, each one representing a different "pattern" of the image. The "pattern" is what is inside each kernel.

The CNN, through the back-propagation in a supervised training, will automatically learn the values to put inside each kernel. For example, one kernel could have the format

000
111
000

meaning that it will detect horizontal lines.

I think the kernel is what you refer as the **mask**.

Finally, all the 16 28x28 images can be concatenated to form some **features** that can be used as the input of a fully connected layer to obtain the classification output.

Note that this explanation is quite simplistic, as it skips some passages (deep convolutions, pooling, etc...) but I hope it will suffice for your doubts.